# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined Three.js 62 version

Tags: three.js, mesh

Can any body help me on this issue on three.js version 62 when using THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(obje, mesh); method ..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when trying to use a MeshFaceMaterial with the merged mesh. In my case I had to modify the materialIndex of each face of the cube I merged.

I assumed that a CubeGeometry by default used materialIndex=0 for all faces. It doesn't! Each side of the cube has its own index.

Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ThPPA/4/

```
var materials = [
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00
}),
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffff00
}),];

var dummy = new THREE.Geometry();

var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
for(var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++) {
    geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = 0;
}

var cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
cube1.position.x -= 1;
THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(dummy, cube1, 0);

var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
cube1.position.x += 1;
THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(dummy, cube2, 1);

var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(dummy, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```